# Big O complexities of algorithms - LZW and Huffman

Tags: algorithm, compression, big-o, time-complexity, space-complexity

What are the space and time complexities, in Big O notation, for the Lempel-Ziv-Welch and Huffman compression algorithms? Google is failing me.

Thanks,

Francisco

Comment: Do you have an implementation in mind? Please post code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the dictionary size is fixed and independent of the input length, [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) is in O(*n*) as each byte is only read once and the complexity of the operation for each character is constant.

And [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is also in O(*n*): First you count the number of occurrences for each input byte, then you sort it and build the output encoding.

Comment: You only need to sort the frequencies of the bytes, not the text itself, right? So Huffman should be O(n) in the size of the text for a constant alphabet.

Comment: @Igor Nazarenko: Yes, it’s the alphabet that needs to be sorted. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the implementation. They get better all the time. "Huffman" is a bit too common a term. For example, you could mean an explicit tree, an implicit, a dynamic one...
But in any case, I guess if you do it *very* clever you should be able to implement alomost any "Huffman" on *O(n)*, with *n* being the text-length.

LZW is also implementation-dependent. I do not know off-hand what "O" common implementations have. I guess with big tables you probably have something like *O(n log n)*, but thats just a guess.

Comment: The LZW compression dictionary has tree character. If stored accordingly, the dictionary can be traversed one node per input byte, essentially making the compression algorithm O(n)-time based on input length. Storing the dictionary that way probably wastes lots of memory, so it's the usual speed-space trade-off and a memory-efficient implementation likely is at least O(n log n) as you mentioned.

Comment: O(n) over input length? And how large would the tree become? More then O(n)? Can't be, because to write a tree bigger then O(n) you need also more then O(n) time. Therefore, why does this O(n) dictionary waste space? O(n) would sound quite optimal. Assuming the dictionary needs lets say 10 bytes per input char that _is_ a lot of memory, but if its worth it... Therefore my question: Is it really O(n)?

Comment: The problem is getting from one node to the next considering the new input value. Getting that part to be O(1) is the trick. And I doubt that is easily possible without either making each tree node work like a hash table or simply having an array with length equal to the alphabet size. A hash table can still be O(1), but there's still that infamous constant factor and the overhead of potentially having to grow the table. BTW: If you allow the tree to grow indefinitely, its number of nodes will equal the input length.

Comment: @Wormbo: Ah, that's what you mean. There are tricks beyond that. [Enhanced Suffix Arrays](http://vmatch.de/AboKurOhl2004.pdf) are one example I know of , I am sure this can (and probably is) applied to LZW as well.